# Having an issue with Backbone View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to Backbone and am trying accomplish some simple tasks, such as rendering list of names from the model. But I'm getting this error:

```
'cannot read property "model" of undefined'
```

I would really appreciate any help with this and any tips in general.

```
var Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getConvertedToHash: function () {
        return $.extend({}, this.attributes.student[0], this.attributes.student[1], this.attributes.student[2]);
    }
});

var Group = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student,
    initialize: function () {
        this.add(new Student({
            student: [
            {
                "name": "john",
                "lastName": "fox",
                "middleName": "yonson"
            },{
                "age": 26,
                "gender": "male"
            },{
                "passport": "qpuid5423",
                "inn": 123542
            }]
        }));
        this.add(new Student({
            student: [
            {
                "name": "john",
                "lastName": "fox",
                "middleName": "yonson"
            },{
                "age": 26,
                "gender": "male"
            },{
                "passport": "qpuid5423",
                "inn": 123542
            }]
        }));        
    }
});

var StudentView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'alert alert-info',
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.model.getConvertedToHash().name);
        return this;
    }
});

var GroupView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('body'),
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.group = new Group();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('student-list');

        _.each(this.group.models, function (element, i) {
            var studentView = new StudentView({
                model: this.group.models[i]
            });
            $ul.append(studentView.render().el);
        });
        thi.$el.append($ul);
    }
});
var groupView = new GroupView();
```

I need that strange method `getConvertedHash()` in a Student Model so I can get one hash instead of an array of objects (as my initial data structure: need it for further purposes).

Comment: The error is because you're attempting to access the property `model` on an undefined object. For example if you were to type `this.group.model` and `this.group` doesn't exist, you'd get this error. I see no evidence of such a scenario in your code, so I believe the error lies elsewhere. If you could provide a jsbin or fiddle where your code doesn't work, that'd help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to use the `.each` iterator the way it is intended to be used:

```
this.group.each(function (model) {
    var studentView = new StudentView({model: model});
    $ul.append(studentView.render().el);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly! I totally messed up with iterator and model.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped your error, the error is that the property `models` doesn't exist. Inside your `render` function it shouldn't say `this.group.models` it should say `this.group.model`.

```
render: function () {
    var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('student-list');

    _.each(this.group.model, function (element, i) { // here
        var studentView = new StudentView({
            model: this.group.model[i] // and here
        });
        $ul.append(studentView.render().el);
    });
    this.$el.append($ul); // also "this" was mistyped
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer! That fixed the occuring error, but unfortunately that's not exactly what I need, because in _.each I need to loop through the objects I'm passing to the collection. And 'models' provide access to the array of models inside of the collection, so I can iterate through them. Here's jsbin with initial code http://jsbin.com/mazodoxusi/edit?js,console,output  thank you again for help in solving my problem!